# Who is Erkki Juhonpoika Puujumala?

Tags: metal

From the last album Luciferian Crown by Archgoat the track Sorcery and Doom lyrics has been dedicated to someone called Erkki Juhonpoika Puujumala.

I have googled and found out that the first and middle name belongs to some noble family but his I don't get a match for his name.
[This is the link to a family member](https://www.geni.com/people/Erkki-%C3%96rni/6000000047910379897)

Who is he ?

Comment: Hmmm...my [query](https://www.google.nl/search?q=erkki+juhonpoika+puujumala&oq=erkki+juhonpoika+puujumala&aqs=chrome..69i57.1078j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) get several full match results, which seem to indicate he was a witch. The 6th hit is even in English.

Answer (score 1):

The only reference that I can locate is in a [document of unknown provenance](https://witchesofthecraft.com/2014/01/08/several-different-account-of-animals-in-witchcraft/) which says:

> Erkki Juhonpoika  Puujumala (“Treegod”) was convicted in Turku Supreme Court.  He was sentenced to death for many reasons –  for killing  people with  witchcraft etc.   He  has had an argument with other people and he had said that he  was going change those people into wolves with his maleficium.  This was not proved to happen, but it was one prosecution among many.   By  the way, Treegod said that he was 120 years old.

The reference to Treegod is pulled through into the first line of the lyric:

> I am the Wooden God.